# Edit an object with the body converter of FosRestBundle

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm using symfony3 and FosRestBundle for backend. To create an object I use the **body converter** `fos_rest.request_body` of Fosrestbundle without FormType.

But when I use the **body converter** to edit an object it doesn't work, no errors but no changes in the database.

```
/**
 * @Rest\Put(
 *    path = "/comments/update/{id}",
 *    name = "app_comment_edit"
 * )
 * @Rest\View(StatusCode = 200, serializerGroups={"edit"})
 * @ParamConverter("comment", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
 */
public function updateAction(Request $request, Comment $comment,$id,  ConstraintViolationList $violations)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $comment = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Comment')->find($id);

    if (count($violations)) {
        return $this->view($violations, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    $em->flush();

    return $comment;
}
```

To make changes , I must use this way with $request:

```
    $comment->setEmail($request->request->get('email'));
    $comment->setContent($request->request->get('content'));
    $em->flush();
```

My question is , the **body converter** of FosUserBundle doesn't work when edit object and I must use the way above or using FormType ?

Answer (score 0):

YOu have to call before saving object:

```
******
$em->persist($comment);
$em->flush();
```

For example here:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database

Comment: persist() Is required when create new object but not required when modify an existing object